# statistical tests for average data

Tags: data-visualization

I'm working on visualising for some data set. I was going to run some statistical tests on the data set, but I'm not sure if I can run some tests or not. I'm sorry that I cannot put the data set here.

Basically, the data set is a csv file. And all the data in the file is an average value. I wonder if I can run a statistical test, such as ANOVA (or making a correlation matrix), for this data where all the inputs are average values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have sample sizes and standard deviations as well as the means then you should be able to do Anova. But I get the feeling that you only have the mean

Comment: I only have the means and the population sizes. I don't have any other information. So can I not use any statistical tests? Also can I not use a correlation matrix either?

Comment: Without the standard deviation, you have no measure of spread which a lot of statistical tests rely on. For a correlation matrix, you would definitely need the raw data. Sorry.